# How to authenticate users of ASP.Net Core website with JWT?

Tags: authentication, asp.net-core, .net-core, jwt

I am wondering, if JWT should be attached to the header of my request **manually**, how can I use JWT to authenticate the users of my ASP.Net Core website?

In other words, how can I tell my browser to attach the token in the header when sending the request to my server? Let us say the user of my website got this token from one of my website's API.

Or is JWT usable only for WebAPI (where I can manually build the request)?

Comment: There's nothing stopping you from just using a cookie is there? Simplest is: avoid JWT.

Comment: @pvg, I am just asking to know if JWT are usable with websites.

Comment: JWT are token-based authentication. you use them when you need to restrict certain parts of your API as they provide a way to pass permissions as well so you don't need to call the database every time to check if user X has permission to see page Y... you generate that token upon login and for each call you need to use it... that token has a sliding expiration time. so it can't be reuse. if it's just a webpage, you can use simpler mechanisms such as sessions.

Comment: @balexandre, clear, but that still does not answer the main question, I find no scenario or idea how they are usable by a website. Are they usable by websites? or only by WebAPI (where I can manually set the request header).

Comment: depends on where the website data comes from... if all data comes from an API, then **it's recommended**. you would call (for example `/api/login`) and get the token to be used in any subsequential request. If the data comes from the website it self, there's no point  of using it, though you would of course use it if you want. [here's a nice post](https://jonhilton.net/2017/10/11/secure-your-asp.net-core-2.0-api-part-1---issuing-a-jwt/) when to use it and how

Answer (score 2):

There are different ways to use JWT tokens. Since JWT is just a token format, it does imply the method used for authentication.

However, JWTs are mainly used for Bearer authentication scheme, which requires adding a custom header to each request. Single page applications (SPAs) that create requests in JavaScript on the client to access API endpoints can do that which is why Bearer+JWT is used a lot in SPAs. SPAs also benefit from the embedded JSON format since they can read expiration dates and other information (claims embedded in the token, ID token contents obtained via OpenID Connect etc.).

For "traditional" server-rendered views and links, using JWTs is hard since they'd have to be set as cookie or made part of the URL (practically impossible because of URL length restrictions). ASP.NET Core 2.0 does not contain any JWT-based cookie logic but it is possible to create a custom implementation using JWTs as cookies. See [this GitHub project](https://github.com/explorer14/JwtAuthenticationHelper) and related [blog post](https://amanagrawal.blog/2017/09/18/jwt-token-authentication-with-cookies-in-asp-net-core/) for a sample implementation. Note that the only benefit of using JWTs in cookie authentication is that the server doesn't have to persist cookie information and share cookies across multiple instances.

To sum up the current state:

- Prefer default cookie authentication when you use server-side rendering and links to avoid creating custom cookie implementations.
- Prefer JWT bearer authentication if you have single page applications (SPAs)  apps that build requests in javascript/typescript on the client.